# Когда нужно делать экранирование данных?

Tags: база-данных, экранирование

Когда нужно делать экранирование данных (например real_escape_string или из php) - до добавления в базу или при выводе на экран ?

если сделаю до, то при поиске из базы не будут ли сложности?
если сделаю после (т.е. при выводе экранирование) будет каждая запись экранировать, беспокоюсь за пустой напряг сервера

Comment: Используйте bind_param вместо подстановки переменной непосредственно в текст запроса и забудьте про real_escape как класс. после чего при выводе вам достаточно заменить `<` на `&lt;` и вы полностью защищены как то sql-инъкций, так и от XSS и прочих клиентских атак

Answer (score 2):

Долгие годы SQL-запросы выполнялись как есть, строкой. Если в такую строку помещалась переменная приходилось тщательно следить, чтобы 
она не содержала в своем составе составленный злоумышленником SQL-фрагмент, изменяющий логику запроса - SQL-инъекцию

```
"SELECT name FROM tbl WHERE id = $id"
```

Например, если в `$id` поместить строку `"0 UNION SELECT password FROM tbl WHERE id = 234"`, то вместо имени пользователя можно вывести пароль/хэш пароля пользователя с идентификатором 234. Если число достаточно легко обезопасить приведением к числу, то в случае строк это сложнее

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE nickname = '$name'"
```

Для такого запроса инъекция может выглядеть следующим образом `"' OR nickname='root'"`. Исключать кавычки нельзя, так как имена пользователей могут их содержать - их нужно экранировать, т.е. превратить этот фрагмент в `"\' OR nickname=\'root\'"`. Существует много функций и методов, позволяющих это делать, один из них метод `real_escape_string()`, который вы упомянули в вопросе. Экранирование всегда осуществляется **до** вставки в базу данных, чтобы корректно интерполировать переменную и избежать SQL-инъекций.

Однако, в последние годы не принято вставлять переменные непосредственно в запрос - это считается плохим тоном, создает угрозу безопасности. Вместо этого, используют подготовленные запросы, в которых используются параметры. Ниже приводится пример с использованием расширения PDO (аналогичный подход используется и для расширения mysqli)

```
<?php
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
      'root',
      '',
      [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

    $query = "SELECT
                `text`
              FROM
                tbl
              WHERE
                id = :id";
    $tbl = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $tbl->execute(['id' => 3]);

    $row_images = $tbl->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row_images);
    echo "</pre>";
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Вы составляете запрос, используя токены, в данном случае `:id`, которые заполняются на этапе выполнения запроса методом `execute()`. При таком подходе SQL-инъекции исчезают как класс и вам не требуется выполнять экранирование в строках.

Существует и другая угроза - XSS-инъекции, вставка злономеренных HTML/JS-конструкций с целью изменения логики поведения JS-части сайта (как вариант кража cookie, паролей, искажение дизайна сайта и т.п.). Для борьбы с ними весь вывод из базы данных все HTML-символы преобразуются в безопасную форму при помощи функции `htmlspecialchars()`. Текст преобразуется **после** извлечения из базы данных. Во-первых, так вы можете сохранить оригинальную строку, введенную пользователем и провести расследование ситуации, во-вторых у вас нет проблем с редактированием: при многократном редактировании есть вероятность того, что HTML-сущности многократно преобразуются

```
& => &amp; => &amp;amp; => &amp;amp;amp;
```

Хотя в новых версиях PHP, функция `htmlspecialchars()` может распознавать такую ситуацию, лучше не допускать ее и использовать `htmlspecialchars()` всегда после извлечения из базы данных.

Answer (score 1):

До добавления. Экранирование как раз и убирает то что не должно быть.

Comment: потом, не будет ли сложности при поиске? и база будет весить больше? Может есть в mysql встроенные функции при выводе экранирует как то?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: На чтении документации. Экранируют для того что бы нельзя или же сложнр было сделать SQL Injection. Экранировать вывод из базы нет смысла. но если у вас в тексте хранящемся в базе есть html или script теги то их тоже надо подавить если вам не нужно обратное.